# Stop and restart containers with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When i restart `docker-compose up` after close this (with CTRL+C), i've message with 'MySQL already setup' or 'httpd exited with code 0'.

So i check `docker ps`, but i've 0 active container. And with :

`docker ps -a`

All container are status Exited.

Anyone have idea about this ? Why my container run good on the first time, but not after stop.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose up` runs containers in the foreground. When you exit the process inside a foreground with `Ctrl-C` the container exits too.

These sound like they should run in the background, so you can run `docker-compose rm` to **delete** the existing containers, and then run `docker-compose up -d` to start your containers in the background.

When they're running in the background you can control the lifecycle with `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose start`.

Comment: Hi Elton, i've same problem with `docker-compose up -d` : if i `stop` (with your command) and i `start`, don't work (not all container start). I need to rm ^^

Comment: Can you post your `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: It's not my compose, i use this : https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox/blob/master/docker-compose.yml